# SQL - An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-merge

Hello and good day to everyone. Could you help me correct this SQL sequence?

```
MERGE INTO table2 WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target
USING
(
  SELECT column1,
         AccessDate,
         AccessCount,
         column4,
         column5, 
         column6, 
         column7, 
         column8
  FROM  table1
  GROUP BY column1, column4, column5, column6, column7, column8
) AS source
ON target.column1 = source.column1 AND
   target.column5 = source.column5 AND
   target.column6 = source.column6 AND
   target.column7 = source.column7 AND
   target.column8 = source.column8
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET target.LastAccessDate = MAX(source.AccessDate),
   target.LastWeeklyAccessCount = (SELECT SUM(source.AccessCount))
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
   INSERT (column1, LastAccessDate, LastWeeklyAccessCount, column4, column5, column6, column7, column8)
    VALUES (source.column1, source.AccessDate, source.AccessCount, source.column4, source.column5, source.column6, source.column7, source.column8);
```

I'm getting an *"aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement"* error when I try to run it because of these two lines:

```
target.LastAccessDate = MAX(source.AccessDate),
target.LastWeeklyAccessCount = (SELECT SUM(source.AccessCount))
```

My code should update in target the `AccessDate` to be the max of AccessDates from in the group and the `LastWeeklyAccessCount` to be the sum of counts in the group.

When no matching records are found just insert. I've worked with SQL like 2 years ago but can't remember much so any help is aprreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because AccessDate,AccessCount in select column list of source statement not appear in group by list:

```
    MERGE INTO table2 WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS target
    USING
    (
      SELECT column1,
             MAX(AccessDate) AS AccessDate,
             SUM(AccessCount) AS AccessCount,
             column4,
             column5, 
             column6, 
             column7, 
             column8
      FROM  table1
      GROUP BY column1, column4, column5, column6, column7, column8
    ) AS source
    ON target.column1 = source.column1 AND
       target.column5 = source.column5 AND
       target.column6 = source.column6 AND
       target.column7 = source.column7 AND
       target.column8 = source.column8
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET target.LastAccessDate = source.AccessDate,
       target.LastWeeklyAccessCount = source.AccessCount
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
       INSERT (column1, LastAccessDate, LastWeeklyAccessCount, column4, column5, column6, column7, column8)
        VALUES (source.column1, source.AccessDate, source.AccessCount, source.column4, source.column5, source.column6, source.column7, source.column8);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Another problem appeared after I updated the statement. `Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.table2'`. Because of the `INSERT` statement `WHEN NO MATCHED`